# Save xspdocument with attachment runs into error

Tags: file-upload, xpages

I'm using an upload control with this code:

```
<xp:table>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:button id="buttonUpload"value="Upload"rendered="#{javascript:docApplication.isEditable();}">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:docApplication.save()}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:button>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:fileUpload id="fuAttachments" value="#{docApplication.Attachments}">
        </xp:fileUpload></xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```

So all I want to do is, to upload a file to the current document and then save the document. I choose a document and as soon as I click Upload I get this error:

The translated error message:

> Script interpreter error, line = 1, col = 43: [TypeError] While
>   calling the methode NotesXspDocument an error occurred.
>   NotesXspDocument(save) access to the file or to change the
>   NotesXspDocument is not allowed

This error only occurs on our production server, but not on our test server. If I do the exact same steps on our test server, the document is saved. But on the production server, I get this error message. So what's the problem? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `docApplication.save()` and the event handler. add `type="submit"` (in the UI) to the button. This will trigger a full form submission and save what needs to be saved.